# How to append a "label" to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array created such as:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
y = np.asarray([x])
```

which prints out

```
  x=[[1 2 3 4]
     [5 6 7 8]]

  y=[[[1 2 3 4]
     [5 6 7 8]]]
```

What I would like is an array such as

```
[0 [[1 2 3 4]
  [5 6 7 8]]]
```

What's the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's that `0` in your expected output?

Comment: have a look at [numpy.insert](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)

Comment: There are many ways to "label" the data.  You could just have another array where each respective element is the label for the data in that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you're asking, just use the phrase

```
labeledArray = [0, x]
```

This way, you will get a standard list with 0 as the first element and a Numpy array as the second element.

However, in practice, you are probably trying to label for the purpose of later recall. In that case, I'd recommend you use a dictionary, as it is less confusing to keep track of:

```
myArrays = {}
myArrays[0] = x
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
>>> myArrays
{0: array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8]])}
>>> myArrays[0]
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: For my purposes the first method is actually perfect, thanks!

Comment: To be picky about terminology, this creates a list containing the number (label) and the numpy array.