# amortization/loan table without using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, calculator

What would be the best way to create a monthly amortization table without using pandas? Say I am given the amount of the loan, the annual interest rate, and the duration in years. How can I make a table that gives the period, beginning balance, principle, interest, and then the ending balance? And then the amount in the ending be equal to 0.
For example if I had a 150,000 loan, 10% rate, and a duration of 25 years (300 months), I don't want to use user input on this though

Formatted something like this (output will be super long I know):

```
month      begin bal.    interest     principal    end bal.
1          xxxx          xxxx         xxxx         xxxx
.
.
```

I can attach what I have started on, but I know it is horrible lol, I am horrible with formulas/tables in Python it just does not click with me so I am struggling. Anything will help, thanks!

```
#p = r(pv)/(1-(1+r)**-n)
loan = 150000  
rate = 10/100 #10%
term = 25 #25 years

for i in range(loanTerm):
    print("month.  begin bal.   interest.   principal.  ending bal")
    beginB = loanAmt
    pv = loan
    r = rate/100
    n = term*12
    p = r(pv)/(1-(1+r)**-n)
```

^ I know that is a very sad attempt with many errors I am embarrassed LOL just don't even know where to start. Let me know if there is anything I need to clarify!

Comment: Would [numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768688/how-to-append-a-label-to-a-numpy-array) work for you?

Comment: @Krzysztofik sure!

Comment: I answered a similiar question here.[Interest calculator in Python. Find total sum and how much to pay each year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64055752/interest-calculator-in-python-find-total-sum-and-how-much-to-pay-each-year/64055882#64055882)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start out with, you compute all of your constants before the loop.

```
#p = r(pv)/(1-(1+r)**-n)
loan = 150000  
rate = 10/100 #10%
term = 25

mo_rate = rate/12
mo_term = term*12
factor = (1 + mo_rate) ** mo_term
pmt = round(loan * (mo_rate * factor) / (factor - 1), 2)
print( "Payments are", pmt, "per month")

balance = loan
print( "month\tbal\tint\tprin\tending" )
for i in range(mo_term):
    interest = balance * mo_rate
    ending = balance + interest - pmt
    print( f"{i}\t{balance:.2f}\t{interest:.2f}\t{pmt-interest:.2f}\t{ending:.2f}" )
    balance = ending
```